# react passing data from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs

I set state to array in App(parent) component. Data is ok the thing is when I try to pass these data to VideoList(child) component it always welcomes as empty string
index js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';

const YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCI9gcceui5zcQDAEwbyvL...";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {videos:''} 
    YTSearch({key:YOUTUBE_API_KEY, term:'surfboards'}, (videos)=>{
      this.setState({videos:videos})
    });

  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar />
      <VideoList videos = {this.state.videos} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

VideoList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_list_item';

    const VideoList = (props) =>{
//I expect props as array but its empty string..
        const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
            return <VideoListItem video={video} />
        })
        return (
                <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
                    {videoItems}
                </ul>
            );
    }
    export default VideoList;
```

I am able to see retrieved video elements inside array so my problem is about passing it to child component

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? You're setting `this.state.videos` to a string, then calling `map` on it, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @JoshKelley Yeah I already figured out, its my solution but so dont support delete posts so if you mind please post this as answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `videos` to a string:

```
this.state = {videos:''}
```

then trying to map on it:

```
const videoItems = props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem video={video} />
})
```

This is probably throwing an error (you should be able to check your console to see it), and errors can prevent further rendering from occuring.