# Passing data to a Child Component React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have read:
[react passing data from parent to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697829/react-passing-data-from-parent-to-child-component)
and
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pass-data-between-components-in-react/

While they outline the desired method.  It does not seem to be working for the following example.  I must be doing something obvious, but I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

**Structure**
The structure is a wizard style form (4 steps) below which is contained in newrequest.js.  Below each step is a list table component with various items associated with each step.

Think of it like a shopping cart, except you can have multiple carts (step 1), you can leave them in the store filled with all sorts of things (step 2-3) for quite some time before buying anything (step 4).

A user many want to create several carts all at the time, and then add/create/edit other items to the carts over the course of several months before finalizing.  The carts, and the items in those carts need to stay grouped together, and they need to be found easily enough by the user to keep working on them at some later date.

**User Action:**
The user goes to step 1, either makes a new cart, or grabs an existing cart to edit and proceeds to step 2.  For the edit option, I have been able to pass the id of an existing cart (list-request-saved.js) to (newrequest.js), edit, save etc.  I can also tie the items to the cart with a cartid prop when this is happening the first time.

**The Problem:**
The issue is I cannot seem to figure out how to pass the cartid aka`requestID`, to step 2 when editing an existing cart aka`SavedRequest` so the database can fetch the items which belong in that cart.  Without the cartid, the database just spits out all items in any cart by anyone.  To fix this, I would need to get the cartid to "newrequest.js" from the child component "list-requests-saved.js " in step 1 (This works ok) and then pass the cartid to child component "list-components.js" in step 2 (This does not work ok).

**newrequest.js (parent) // Removed the non-impacting sections**

```
//queries
import { listTestRequests } from '../../graphql/queries'
import { listComponents } from '../../graphql/queries'
import { getSavedRequest } from '../../graphql/queries'
import { getComponent } from '../../graphql/queries'

//components
import SavedRequests from "../../pages/list-requests-saved"
import Components from "../../pages/list-components"

const initialTestRequestState = getInitialState(listTestRequests)
const initialComponentState = getInitialState(listComponents)

function NewRequest(props) {
  const [testRequest, setTestRequest] = React.useState(initialTestRequestState)
  const [component, setComponent] = React.useState(initialComponentState)
  const [editRequest, setEditRequest] = React.useState('')
  const [editComponent, setEditComponent] = React.useState('')

  const requestTableToParent = (requestID) => {
    setEditRequest(requestID)
  }

  const componentTableToParent = (componentID) => {
    setEditComponent(componentID)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRequest(editRequest)
    async function fetchRequest(id) {
      if (!id) return
      const requestData = await API.graphql({ query: getSavedRequest, variables: { id } })
      setTestRequest(requestData.data.getSavedRequest)
    }
  }, [editRequest])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchComponent(editComponent)
    async function fetchComponent(id) {
      if (!id) return
      const componentData = await API.graphql({ query: getComponent, variables: { id } })
      setComponent(componentData.data.getComponent)
    }
  }, [editComponent])

return (
    <form
      autoComplete="off"
      noValidate
      {...props}
    >

      {
        activeStep == 0
          ? <SavedRequests requestTableToParent={requestTableToParent}/>
          : null
      }
      {
        activeStep == 1
          ? <Components componentTableToParent={componentTableToParent} requestID={editRequest}/>
          : null
      }
    </form >
  )
}

export default NewRequest
```

**list-requests-saved.js  (child-step-1) // Removed the non-impacting sections**

```
function SavedRequests({requestTableToParent}) {

  const renderEditButton = (params) => {
    return (
      <strong>
        <Button
          variant="text"
          color="primary"
          size="small"
          style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}
          onClick={() => requestTableToParent(params.row.id)}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>
      </strong>
    )
  }
export default (SavedRequests)
```

**list-components.js  (child-step-2) // Removed the non-impacting sections**

```
import { listComponents } from '../graphql/queries'
import { deleteComponents as deleteComponentsMutation } from '../graphql/mutations'

function Components({componentTableToParent}, {requestID}) {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState([])
  const classes = useStyles();

  console.log("requestID", requestID) //this is undefined
}

export default (Components)
```

**Additional Commentary:**  `editRequest` in "newrequest.js" has the correct value which was set by the edit button in "list-requests-saved.js".  When I'm trying to catch the value in the child component "list-components.js", `requestID` is reporting as undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: React components props are destructured from a single `props` object. The `Components` signature should look like: `function Components({ componentTableToParent, requestID })`.

Comment: This is correct, and I can confirm it works great.  Can you structure this as an answer for the community?  I have read quite a few examples but this is not raised in any of them.